# Html.Actionlink only to be enabled conditionally and have dynamic submitting value

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an ASP MVC website and have encountered a problem.

The page I'm working on has a drop down box which returns the value 'location' and one that returns 'name'. The 'location' drop down box filters the names for any in that location from the database. Underneath this is the option to add an additional name.

I would like to add a hyperlink to a name edit location but since it's possible there are no names under that current location then it throws an exception when there is a name.id value of null and I doubt it would dynamically change the name value the hyperlink would post even if it ignored the original problem.

Anyone have any idea how I could do this elegantly?

Comment: Are you allowed to use javascript and jQuery?

Comment: Oh yes, forgot to mention. The names select box is populated with jquery using an ajax function when the location box is changed

Comment: So are you changing the param in the hyperlink to submit the id of the `name` for edit? I think the most elegant would be to change the id value using jQuery and disable the link when the dropdown has no options? let me know if I am close and I'll find some code, might I suggest you also tag this as post as jQuery?

Comment: Yes! That would be brilliant. My main problem is setting a name for the drop down name box, I can't seem to work out how to do it in ASP MVC

Comment: Can you post the aspx code that generates your drop-down, so that we can see what you're currently doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve the problem with JQuery...

Put in a boolean variable that sets to 'true' if any names are returned or 'false' if no names are returned for that location.

Made a function to update the link you click one to edit the name's location and put that at the end of when the ajax gets a new list of names:

```
var updateEditLink = function() {
        if(hasValues == true) {
            var segmentsOfLink = $('#EditName').attr('href').split("/");
            var newLink = "/" + segmentsOfLink[1] + "/" + segmentsOfLink[2] + "/" + $("#ChangesForm select[name=Name]").val() + "/" + segmentsOfLink[4] + "/" + segmentsOfLink[5];

            $('#EditName').attr('href', newLink);
        }
    }
```

The newLink is created in that way because it is set out as /Name/Edit/{NumberToChange}/Value/Value.

Then when the EditName hyperlink is pressed it calls this function

```
$("#EditName").click(function() {
            return hasValues;
        });
```

That means if the Location select box has no values then the link does not navigate away from that page